# How do I convince Ubuntu to connect to a limited network?

Tags: networking, windows, lan, wired

I'm trying to create a LAN network not connected to the internet, where 6 computers can talk to each other through a switch, but none can talk to the internet. (If I connected it to the internet a modification to a program I wrote would be overwritten,I cannot connect to the internet) Windows can connect to a wired network that doesn't have internet access as a limited network, but Ubuntu doesn't seem capable. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are your Windows systems connecting using [zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)? If so, change the network settings to use link-local configuration.

Comment: Would it be easier to just connect to a router instead of a switch, and let it do DHCP?